# Run a AJAX query which uses PHP code that limits queries/sec on client side?

Tags: php, ajax

I have a PHP Code, that uses a web service to query some data. However, this web service limits queries per second based on the server (i m not sure about the exact mechanism, but it seems to be the IP address)

I m using ajax to query this data from a PHP file on my server, but is there some way I can let my client search this data for themselves by faking that they are requesting the data rather than my servers?

The issue is I am getting a RateExceeded error message from server, as soon as two clients are requesting the same page, which is rather obvious since the webservice is only seeing one server, which is my server.

So, can I somehow, make it happen that when these clients query the data, the service is rather thinking that the request is being originated via these clients, rather than my server.

Comment: Not directly related, but could you cache the results on your server? That way, if two clients ask for the same information in a short span of time, the second client will receive the cached version from your server, and the web service never sees the second request. That might help somewhat with the rate problem.

Comment: Yeah, I've given this a thought earlier, and this is what I have had in mind, if I do not find a solution for the question I have posted above. The reason that this is not exactly what I want is that I "do" want the clients to directly access the webservice so that the records the servers fetches v/s collective records the clients fetch are one to many... so like work of one week by server alone, can be done in one day with 7 clients... :)

Comment: From the WS point of view, you don't *have* 7 clients, you have 1 client with 7 times the requests. Hmmm...

Comment: Yeah, if I m using an access token, right? What if, no access token is being used? Thats the point, I understand that the WS is seeing only one client, and I want it to see 7 instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't really *fake* it, but if you could query the webservice directly via AJAX, it should be seeing the clients' IP addresses. Note that if you're doing any kind of processing on the data that the WS returns, you'd have to perform it in JavaScript, on the client side.

If the request from your server to the WS contains any confidential data (e.g. some kind of access key) which the clients must not see, this approach is useless.

Comment: actually this is a collection of services and each service is queried with a php class in my script via a Master class. so I guess, in a way this is possible. Can you link me to somethin similar please, some tutorial? I m just starting with Ajax, in a way!